# How to use specific library for specific perl modules?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have two libraries that I use and under them are modules that I need:

- **perl_lib/foo**

  - person.pm
  - dictionary.pm
- **perl_lib/bar**

  - person.pm

I want use **perl_lib/foo** for the **dictionary.pm** module but I want to use the **perl_lib/bar** for the **person.pm** module.

I understand that the order of the use lib lines matter here, and the following would let me use bar/Person.pm, then foo/Dictionary.pm:

```
use lib 'perl_lib/bar';
use lib 'perl_lib/foo';
```

but, in our code, perl_lib/bar is exported outside of the perl script while perl_lib/foo is still being used as shown above:

```
export PERL5LIB='perl_lib/bar:$PERL5LIB'
```

And with this, perl_lib/foo would get priority for Person.pm

Are there other ways to specify which libraries to get the specific module?

I've tried this:

```
push @INC, 'perl_lib/foo'
```

So that foo would get the last priority. (Using, use acts like an 'unshift' to @INC. and the last one that gets unshifted would get priority) It's works but it's a bit messy. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Are those different versions of person.pm, or are the modules really foo::person and bar::person?

Comment: Those are different versions of the same module person.pm

Answer (score 4):

The contents of `PERL5LIB` and the parameters to `use lib` are *unshifted* onto the start of the `@INC` array, so if you have

```
export PERL5LIB=a:b
```

and then run a program

```
use lib qw/ c d /;
use lib e;
```

the your `@INC` array will now start with

```
'e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'b', ...
```

The libraries are scanned by the `use` statement in the order that they appear in `@INC`, so in general the *last* folder added to the array is the one that is searched *first*. It sounds like you want to scan `perl_lib/bar` followed by `perl_lib/foo` so as to find the correct `person.pm` file. You can create that with

```
use lib qw{ perl_lib/bar perl_lib/foo };
```

or

```
use lib 'perl_lib/foo';
use lib 'perl_lib/bar';
```

which is the opposite of what you already have. I feel that putting all of the directories into a single `use lib` better represents the order in which they will be added to `@INC`, and so their search priority

As for the contents of `PERL5LIB`, you can `use lib` to add that directory again with a different priority. The old entry from the environment variable will still be there, but it will simply be searched twice. If you want to keep things tidy and make a fractional improvement to your compilation time then you can remove it first with

```
no lib 'perl_lib/bar'
```

before adding the directories in the order you really want

One more thing, your files should be `Person.pm` and `Dictionary.pm`, and they should contain `package Person` and `package Dictionary` respectively

> I've tried this:
>
> ```
> push @INC, 'perl_lib/foo'
> ```
>
> So that foo would get the last priority. (Using, use acts like an 'unshift' to `@INC`. and the last one that gets unshifted would get priority) It's works but it's a bit messy. Is there a better way to do it?

I'm not sure what you mean here. As I've said, perl scans the contents of `@INC` from the *beginning*, so using a `push` will just add another, very low priority directory to the search list. If that directory already appears elsewhere in the array then the addition will make no difference except that the directory will be searched a second time before perl declares that it cannot find a module file

---

#### Update

You've asked for a way to employ `use` to load a specific module irrespective of the contents of `@INC`. That didn't seem to be the drive of your original question, but you can do that using `require`, which allows a file path to be specified instead of a bareword module name. You should put it into a `BEGIN` block, and if your module uses `Exporter` then you also need to call the `import` subroutine, like this

```
BEGIN {
    require 'perl_lib/bar/Person.pm';
    Person->import();
}
```

but this is very ugly Perl, and I can't recommend hard-coding module paths into your programs. You've said that you consider `push @INC, 'perl_lib/foo'` to be a *bit messy* so I don't know if it helps

You could also temporarily override the entire contents of `@INC` for that one library, like this

```
BEGIN {
    local @INC = 'perl_lib/bar';
    require Person;
    Person->import();
}
```

but I'm not sure whether that's an improvement

Please let me know if I've now interpreted your question correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand how the order goes for \@INC, I'm more interested if there's a better way of using the specific module without relying on the order of \@INC.

Comment: @the_qbf: I'm sorry, but to me your question gave every indication that you *didn't* understand that. It would help if you explained what underlying problem has caused you to ask this question, as I don't understand why `use lib qw{ perl_lib/bar perl_lib/foo }` isn't a satisfactory solution. I've added an update to my answer that may help you

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Yup, the update that you have is what I really meant for the question. So the `use lib qw{ perl_lib/bar perl_lib/foo }` isn't really the best solution for me because the other library is strictly exported outside of the perl script and that's why I try to use the `push @INC, perl_lib/foo` as it gives me a ability to prioritize perl_lib/bar over that lib.  I may consider moving that in the perl script to make use of this solution you provided.